# Unmanaged Windows Service with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-services, unmanaged

What's the best & fastest way to create an unmanaged Windows service with Visual C++ 2010?

Remark: From the lack of search results for this issue I'm suspecting this is either not recommended or trivial (a regular executable) - but I'm checking this for a colleague which insists not using the CLR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it in VS2010, but it used to be fairly simple to create a Windows Service using ATL. As far as I remember there was even a project template for doing this.

Here's a [CodeGuru article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/atl/article.php/c3553) describing how to do it in VC++ 6.0.

Edit: Seems like it's still supported in VS2010 since it's still in the docs: [ATL Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74y2334x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)